# ExpandableListView groupItem inside Fragment+ViewPager cuts off half of the item horizontally

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I have a ExpandableListView inside of a fragment inside of a ViewPager.

The issue is that the group item is being cut in half horizontally, show below in the image.

I have the same exact code for the ExpandableListView elsewhere in the application, but inside of an activity, and it works fine?

XML layout for the group item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbl_exercise_group"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:background="@color/material_blue_500"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was: in my ExpandableListView XML definition `layout_width` was set to `wrap_content`, it needed to be `fill_parent`

I changed:

```
 <ExpandableListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/exList_exercises"
        android:clickable="true"
        />
```

to

```
<ExpandableListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/exList_exercises"
        android:clickable="true"
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the layout_with from The TextView should be match_parent for the full size.

Comment: Same result after I change both values to match_parent

Comment: Have you tried to change the layout_width only in the TextView element

Comment: It still looks the same when I change it to any combination